# How to distinguish folder and file without extensions?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to distinguish files without this extension from folders, how to distinguish them from each other in VB NET. I have to differentiate them for logging . File without extension generated from excel file modification , like this ..

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this:

```
Dim filesWithOutExtension As List(Of String) = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\UserName\Documents\").Where(Function(el) New IO.FileInfo(el).Extension.Length = 0).ToList
```

Comment: doesn't work in my case. file without extensions not found on my disk . It is just a temporary file that appears when editing an excel file

Answer (score 2):

There is a 2'nd parameter to `GetFiles` called `searchPattern` where you can specify `"*."`.

```
Dim filesWithoutExtension = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("c:\temp\", "*.")
```

Comment: doesn't work in my case. file without extensions not found on my disk . It is just a temporary file that appears when editing an excel file

Comment: Then you can only run the program while the temporary file exists using the correct path to the folder.

Comment: I sure about the correct path to the folder , but never found temporary file . but i fixed this bug. thank u .